# Publish a package to Bitbucket or GitHub

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4, package, bitbucket

In my Laravel application I created a packet (located in the workbench directory). Now I'd like to publish it to my private Bitbucket repository so that I can use it in different projects and once it is ready I also like to publish it to GitHub. But I have no idea how to publish only the contents of the new package to a new Bitbucket repo.

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction?

**Update based on Kacy Raye suggestions**

These are the steps I took. To avoid troubles, I created a new dir and cloned the repo to the dir and pushed the repo to a new repo.

```
sudo mkdir <application>
sudo chown <user> <application>
git clone git@bitbucket.org:<user-name>/<old-repo>.git
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:<user-name>/<new-repo>.git
git push origin master
```

With the new repo set-up I now want to push the package (`src` dir is located in `workbench/user-name/package-name/`) to a newly created package repo. These are the steps I took.

```
git remote add <package-name> git@bitbucket.org:<user-name>/<package-name>.git
git checkout -b <package-name>
git rm -r app/ artisan bootstrap/ bower.json composer.json CONTRIBUTING.md phpunit.xml public/ readme.md server.php # all files removed except the workbench dir
git rm -r --cached workbench/ # need only the package
git add workbench/<user-name>/<package-name>/
git commit -m'init'
git push <package-name> master # want the package pushed to the new repo on its master banch
```

And then all files are pushed to the server, not just the files of my repo (not even as i mentioned before just the workbench dir) :(

**Update 2**
On the Laravel IRC chat I discussed the problem and found the solution! I just needed to do a `git init` in the `wordkbench/<vendor>/<package>` dir, add the new remote, git commit, and git push.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the problem is that you have two repos.  One with the overall project and one specifically for the package. 
The goal is that you only want to push the package.

After adding the remote repo specifically for the package, you can switch to a new branch, remove everything you don't want to push from the index (also know as the "staging area"), commit it to your local repo, then push it to the remote repo you want.

```bash
git remote add <whateverYouWantToNameTheRemote> <URL the remote is located at>

git checkout -b shinyNewBranch # (-b creates a new branch and switches to it)

git rm <fileYouDontWant1> <fileYouDontWant2> ...

# (Do a 'git add' here if you did not already add the package to the index)

git commit -m "whatever commit message you want"

git push <theNameYouGaveTheRemote> <branchYouWantToPushTo>
```

Keep in mind that `git rm` without the `--cached` option wil not only remove files from the index, but it will also remove the files from the working directory.  This shouldn't be a problem though so long as you committed the files in the branch you switched from.  When you switch back to that branch using `git checkout branchName`, whatever files were in your most recent commit for that branch will be loaded into the working directory.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm 100% clear on the problem, you want to push this package, and the next time someone does something like a git clone on the remote repo, they will only get the laravel package?

Comment: I just fixed some typos. Sorry now my comment is below yours. The original comment: "Sorry I think I have not been clear enough. This I use to push the whole app to the repo, now I just want the laravel package pushed. Or do I just have to create a new repo and replace my regular push by 'push laravel-package master', where laravel package is the repo name? And where do I have to set my remote for this new (nested) repo?"

Comment: As part of my laravel application I created a package. I have no problem to push the whole application. But have no clue how to push just the package which is in accordance to the laravel manual in the workbench directory. So I want to push just the package to a separate repo.

Comment: I would suggest just creating a new branch, switch to it, and do a `git rm --cached` on all the files you don't want to push. This will remove all the files from the index(staging area) and when you push, the removed files won't be included. You can just do a `git remote add newRemoteRepoName <URL of Repo>` in the working directory to add the remote so you can start pushing to it.
If this sounds like what you're looking for I'll edit my answer with a bit more detail.

Comment: Yes that sounds like what I'm looking for. A branch of my my master will just contain the package. Just one question, there is no (easy) way to push just this part to a new/specific repository?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The way `git push` works is it pushes the contents of the most recent commit to the remote repository.  So if you just want the contents of that package, you'd have to remove everything you don't want in another commit, and then push. I'll edit my answer so the steps are a bit clearer and I'll explain any flags I use.

Comment: It's not working the way I expected. I added my package `git add workbench/martijnthomas/wordcloud` but after commit not just the contents of the wordcloud dir are pushed, but the entire dir (from workbench).

Comment: And you followed the steps I gave exactly?

Comment: I added all my steps taken to my OP.

Comment: Omg I know why this doesn't work.  I've been under the impression that when you do a `git push` you only push the most recent commit, but that's not right.  When you push, it pushes all commits in the history that the remote repository does not have.  So even though your most recent commit did not have the workbench directory, a previous commit did have it.  I'm really sorry for wasting your time but we both learned something! And thank you for posting the solution, that totally makes sense now.